# How can I make a tilted rectangle extend so that its rightmost point aligns with the rightmost point of another tilted rectangle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, snapping

I know this title is impossible to understand, sorry about that...

Here's the actual shape I'm working on:

[image]

So, I wish that the rightmost points of the 4 horizontal rectangles (circled in dark green) to be aligned to the rightmost point of the vertical rectangle (circled in magenta), while the 4 horizontal rectangles can maintain their current location and angle. In other words, only the right edges of them should be moving. And they should still be rectangles after aligning.

Not sure if I'm being clear enough, please lmk if you need further clarifications!

Currently the only snapping on is snap to points, all others are disabled.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Turn on Smart Guides. [See example](https://imgur.com/ozPsz4F).

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you for your comment! But I think your method would cause the position of the rectangle to change, doesn't it? I wish to only move the right edge, and keep everything else (including tilted angle) in place. Johannes's answer below solved this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new anchor point to the wanted place. Then drag the rectangle longer. An example:

[image]

In the left the green line segment is drawn between the corners of a magenta rectangle. It snaps if you have snap to points and smart guides ON.

In the middle the line is dragged longer. The line keeps its direction and snaps to the edge of the yellow rectangle.

In the right the magenta rectangle is dragged longer. It snaps to the line endpoint.

Remove the line.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I understand what you mean. It comes under alignment. Either open the panel under Window > Align or once you select the shapes the option for Align options will appear on the dock.

Select all the shapes and then select the shape you want them to align to by pressing ALT on Windows or OPTION on Mac (Magenta circle). You will need to press Horizontal Distribute Right (Green circle).

Alternatively, if this is not what you mean, I suggest uploading a sketch to provide more context.

[image: Align tool in Illustrator]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I gave it a try, but I don't think this is the effect I want. Your method would have to change the horizontal positions of these rectangles, right? I wish to only move the right edge, and keep everything else (including tilted angle) in place. Johannes's answer below solved this problem.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. I wasn’t sure what you meant tbh. It is hard to explain something when you aren’t sure, which is why I usually draw examples for context.

Answer (score 0):

Right align your shapes, using the top one (magenta circle) as your key object.  Stretch out the left hand sides to an angled guide.

[image]